# Jquery to drag items to table cells in google calendar like fashion

Tags: javascript, jquery

In an attempt to create a calendarlike application sort of like this http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ or maybe this http://thechriswalker.net/select-drag/ and http://neb.net/playground/dragdrop/

I was wondering what the simples approach to using JQuery is. It seems the pages I've found are sort of experimental (except the fullcalendar but the source code for that is 150 kb - ie not a good place to start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the "sortable" plugin for jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ .

Write some custom stylesheets to make some rectangular <ul>s, and make your events <li>s within them.  Then call

```
jQuery('.sortable').sortable({connectWith: '.sortable'})
```

and the li elements will be draggable between ul's.  Add a little ajax to update on the sortchange() event ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-change ) and you're all set.

Comment: 1) how will this allow me to drag these items into a table/grid? and 2) how will this allow me to resize the elements to span several cells?

Comment: 1) You have to do the styling yourself: something like this should work: "ul.calendar { width: 50px; height: 50px; }" and insert breaks at the end of the lines.

Comment: 2) That's separate functionality.  You might be able to use the resizable function with the grid option turned on: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

Comment: looking at http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#photo-manager it seems to do what you suggest. How do I create items can then in turn can contain other items? So a table with cells where you drag "appointments" and then you can drag annotations on the "appointments"

Comment: What kind of annotations?  You may want to just give the user a text field within the `<li>`.

Comment: How dø i add a text field to a list item